# Pygame not displaying the window

Tags: python, pygame

I have a folder called cards which has png playing card images H, D, C and S 01-13.
The card dealer code below works on a Raspberry Pi under Raspbian, but when run in Pycharm (Python 3.4) it executes everything but no window displays. I have put debug print statements (now removed) in each part to check that it did everything, which it did. Any clues please?

```
# prompts to play/quit and for hand size and no of players
#
import random
import pygame
pygame.init()

def main():
    myvar = input("Press P to Play or Q to Quit ")
    if myvar =="p" or myvar=="P":
        getimage()
    else:
        quit()

def getimage():
    n_players = int(input("How many players? "))
    hand_size = int(input("How many cards in a hand? "))
    if n_players * hand_size > 52:
        print("There are only 52 cards, cannot do.")
        main()
    #card suit and rank lists
    suits = 'S H D C'.split()
    ranks = '01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13'.split()

    #generate deck of pngs by list comprehension
    pathw = "cards/"
    deck  = [pathw + s + r + ".png" for r in ranks for s in suits]

    #create Surface as "screen"
    cardw = 77  #actual width = 71
    cardh = 120 #actual width = 96
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode([cardw * hand_size, cardh * n_players])

    #set background colour
    GREEN = (0,102,0)
    screen.fill(GREEN)

    random.shuffle(deck)
    hands = deal(deck, n_players, hand_size, cardw)

    #remove quotes and brackets from string
    c=0
    while c < n_players:
        player1 = str(hands[c])
        player1 = player1.strip("['")
        player1 = player1.strip("']")
        slicep1 (player1, cardw, cardh, c)
        c +=1

    pygame.display.update()
    main()

def slicep1 (player1, cardw, cardh, c):
    pics = player1.split("', '")
    count = 0
    for pic in pics:
        showcards(pic, cardw, cardh, c, count)
        count += 1

def deal(deck, n_players, hand_size, cardw):
    return [deck[i * hand_size:(i+1) * hand_size] for i in range(n_players)]

def showcards(pic, cardw, cardh, c, count):
    pic1 = pygame.image.load(pic)
    main_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
    main_surface.blit(pic1, (count*cardw+1, c*cardh+1))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> BlockquoteThe card dealer code below works on a Raspberry Pi under Raspbian, but when run in Pycharm (Python 3.4) it executes everything but no window displays.

I am guessing that the PyCharm (Python 3.4) comment means that it isn't running on a Raspberry Pi. If that is the case then it seems like you have something wrong with your environment on PyCharm (Python 3.4).

My guess is that your Python 3.4 is not compatible with the Pygame version that was installed. For example, you downloaded and installed the *pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi* when you really needed the 3.4 msi (if you are running windows).

The other possibility is that you are running a 64-bit version of Python and you have the 32-bit version of Pygame installed.

I hope that helps. I can't give a more clear answer without knowing what versions of Python and Pygame the other environment is running.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I am running PyCharm 1.9.2 on a Mac with Python 3.4 interpreter. If I cut out the deal part of the program and just display a hard-coded png file from the card folder, it works. Therefore I agree that it is something in the environment but to do with looping or the passing of variables which I cannot see.